# Spring web service problems returning JSON after enabling CORS on Apache Tomcat

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, spring

I have an Apache Tomcat webserver running on Windows Server 2012

I have a Spring based RESTful web service:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/myMethod")
    public String myMethod(@RequestParam(value="input") String input) throws JSONException{

        JSONObject joResult = new JSONObject();
        joResult.put("status", "success");
        return joResult.toString();    
    }
}
```

Its compiled into a war file and sitting on a web server.

I tried accessing it via Ajax from javascript as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        url:    "http://myserver:8080/myService/myMethod/?input=myInput",
        success: function(msg) {
                console.log("EXCELLENT!");
        },
        error: function(msg) {
                console.log("say what?");
        }
    })
```

I got errors accessing this so I added the following to web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

That took care of my access error.  I was able to verify the service fulfilled the request (it goes and mucks with a database and I was able to query the db and see the change).

The problem is what gets returned.

The error callback in my javascript is executed.  When I print out what is returned, I get:

```
{“readyState”:4,“status”:200,“statusText”:“success”}
```

which hardly looks like an error to me.

Just for laughs, I tried changing the ajax call to

```
dataType: text
```

which resulted in an uglier error being returned even though the action was again completed successfully in the database.

Research indicates there is some kind of disconnect due to @RestController causing Spring to automagically convert whatever it returns to JSON so I changed myMethod to:

```
    @RequestMapping("/myMethod")
    public JSOObject myMethod(@RequestParam(value="input") String input) throws JSONException{

        JSONObject joResult = new JSONObject();
        joResult.put("status", "success");
        return joResult;    
    }
```

which resulted in another undecipherable result.

So, the question is, what do I have to do to return JSON to javascript via an ajax call to a Spring based RESTful web service whose controller is annotated with @RestController?

Comment: first code is returning string, where as second code is returning json object

Comment: yes.  i create the JSON i want to return by loading org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject with the key/value pairs i want to return and then returning the result of .toString().  in the 2nd case i just tried returning the JSONObject itself